# How to customize the initial path to the route of the folder in react?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

When I am doing import of different files I have to be very careful on the folder nesting where do I call the imports.

I know that it is possible to set a generic variable path to import files directly pointing at the route of my SRC folder, but I never done it and I am just unable to find the information on the web about it on how to configure it (every search come around react-router which is not what I need). Could someone explain me how to make it happen:

```js
import dataJSON from "../../data/data.json";
import IconPath from "../../assets/svg/icons.svg";
```

become something approximate like

```js
import dataJSON from "{myRoute}/data/data.json";
import IconPath from "{myRoute}/assets/svg/icons.svg";
```

so that I don't have to worry all the time to think about nest depth when I code and organise my components in folders.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Javascript :

Create a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

> For Typescript:

You already have `tsconfig.json` file in the root of project. Just need to add baseurl setting in compile options key.

```
{
...//other ts config
"compilerOptions": {
    ..., // other complie options
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
...//other ts config
}
```

Here baseUrl is what we're adding into compileoptions.

after adding this file and configuration you can import files as following.

> Before:

`import Component1 from '../../../../Components/Component1'`

> After:

`import Component1 from 'Components/Component1'`

Anything you import will be absolute imports from src folder.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Love it, so simple!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can let your IDE do the work for you (importing and moving files around). The gif below is WebStorm, I believe MS Code does it too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver).

This plugin can simplify the require/import paths in your project. For example, instead of using complex relative paths like `import dataJSON from "../../data/data.json";`, you can write `import dataJSON from "data/data.json";`. It will allow you to work faster since you won't need to calculate how many levels of the directory you have to go up before accessing the file.

**Install the plugin**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

or

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Create a `jsconfig.json` file and use the code.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

That's it.